# java.lang.ClasscastException : java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Tags: java, json, sling

I have written a code for java to Json, while retrieving a Sting value from a Page that is Latitude from a Page properties throwing an `error` : `java.lang.ClassCastException.` Here I am using `ValueMap` if it contains that latitude value then I have to store it in Double. The Code sample is

```
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap
private static final String G_LAT = "37.7608337";
protected ValueMap pageProp;
Double lat = null;
if(pageProp.containsKey(G_LAT))

lat = (Double) pageProp.get(G_LAT); // Getting an exception here
```

Thank You for any help!

Comment: To avoid bad cast, you can cast into `java.lang.Number` as `java.lang.Long` inherits from `java.lang.Number`. Then, use the method `doubleValue()` on the retrieved number.

Comment: Can you please provide some syntax

Comment: `Long longLat = (Long) pageProp.get(G_LAT);` `lat = longLat.doubleValue();`

Comment: after trying the above syntax compiler error and it's forcing me to Change type of lat to double

Comment: I think you have to remove the semi column after the if, you will have: `if(pageProp.containsKey(G_LAT)) {Long longLat = (Long) pageProp.get(G_LAT); lat = longLat.doubleValue();} `

Comment: Still getting compiler error

Answer (score 0):

You can use Double.parseDouble() to convert a String variable to double.

```
String str="2.036"
Double d=Double.parseDouble(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to a cast exception please refer the following url

[java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757565/java-lang-long-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-double)

you can try this instead.
lat = (Double) pageProp.get(G_LAT,long);

The get method returns a Object which will be typecast to the Double which is a narrowing operation. Hence try to convert the object to long before casting that to a Double.